# Why userWorkstations attribute for user accounts filled with domain controllers?

Tags: active-directory, domain, domain-controller

Lately I've noticed that most of the child domain user accounts in the forest, at the place I work, having domain controllers in list of userWorkstations.

I can't really think of why it has been done. Well maybe RemoteApp or it's a security concern or credential pass for SSO application?  Could anyone please explain me why could this been done.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680868(v=vs.85).aspx

**User-Workstations attribute**
*Contains the NetBIOS or DNS names of the computers running Windows NT Workstation or Windows 2000 Professional from which the **user can log on**. Each NetBIOS name is separated by a comma. Multiple names should be separated by commas.*

Answer (score 1):

That attribute is populated when you populate the "Logon To" in the properties of the user account. Why that was done in your environment is a question for the person who did it.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I know that, I just really can't find a fitting reason why it has been done, a guy from work claims it works to authenticate via some system where there is a tons of them(over 100). Thanks anyway.

Comment: OK, I'm not sure why you'd think that we would know why it was done.

Answer (score 0):

late answer but it might help. please check this:
https://discourse.igniterealtime.org/t/openfire-3-7-1-ldap-authentication-failed/57663/4
in this case if you add name of DC to this option - the it allow to logon to openfire under domain account which has already configured User-Workstations attribute.
without adding DC name if wont work.

and for example this:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/101658/userworkstations-attribute-in-ad-preventing-users-from-logging-into-webapp